# FTView ME Acknowledge Alarms

Tags: plc

I would like to be able to press a button on an HMI and have it both acknowledge an ALMD/ALMA alarm in the PLC and also acknowledge it in the Alarm List in the HMI. With a FT Alarm and Events server for FTView SE this would be a piece of cake, but unfortunately I'm running this on a machine.

My thoughts were to somehow use some type of PB to connect to a tag in the PLC to acknowledge the alarm there and also connect it to a macro to push the standard Ack Alarm button that you can link to the alarm list.

Would anyone know how to do that? Or have a better idea of a way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better way:

On many automation platforms (ones that don't utilize the Alarms and Events feature on HMI's) a simple way to do it would be by storing an integer in the PLC. This integer would represent the "Fault Code" or "Alarm Code".

Based on watchdog conditions in the PLC, a different non-zero integer would be moved into the Fault Code address for each fault.

When the Fault Code is not equal to zero, a Fault Bit is active.

This Fault Bit would trigger the alarm screen on the HMI. The "Clear Alarm" PB on the HMI would attempt to move a zero to the Fault Code, and also attempt to re-start the automated sequence or process, in an attempt to "Reset" the fault. If successful, the fault would be cleared. If the attempt is unsuccessful, the fault would simply remain active.

As long as the alarm is displayed on the alarm screen, the HMI will log the fault.